# How do put \overbrace across an (aligned) equals sign?

Tags: align, amsmath, mathtools, underbrace, flalign

I want to have several equations aligned by their equals signs. At the same time, I want to put an overbrace (or bracket) over the left- and right-hand sides of the first equal sign to write a reference to some other equations (this is to explain where this equality comes from). But I get an error if I do both at the same time.

This works but it's not aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
  \overbrace{ f = \sum_{i\in I} a_i  }^{\text{ my notes }} \\
  g &= blabla \\
  h &= blabla
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

I would like something like:

```
  \overbrace{ f &= \sum_{i\in I} a_i  }^{\text{ my notes }} \\
```

but the "&" produces an error. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not quite elegant but works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
  \rlap{$\displaystyle\overbrace{\phantom{f = \sum_{i\in I} a_i}}^{\text{ my notes }}$}
  f &= \sum_{i\in I} a_i  \\
  g &= blabla \\
  h &= blabla
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically you put the expression with the `\overbrace` in a box and print it first. Using `\rlap` the expression is printed without taking any horizontal place. Then you print the expression, this time with the alignment `&`.

The same result can be obtained with `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads also amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
  \mathrlap{\overbrace{\phantom{f = \sum_{i\in I} a_i}}^{\text{ my notes }}}
  f &= \sum_{i\in I} a_i  \\
  g &= blabla \\
  h &= blabla
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second one worked best for me (I mean, both work, but I must have made some mistake trying the first one since the real equations I'm using are long and complicated)

Answer (score 2):

After 20 minutes I have created this MWE, more ugly ( **:-)** ) than the answer of @campa ...but also it works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\[
      \begin{matrix}
      \mathclap{\overbrace{f = \displaystyle \sum_{i\in I} a_i  }^{\text{my notes}}} \\[2ex]
          g= \phantom{\displaystyle \sum_{i\in I} a_i} \hspace{-3.5\tabcolsep}\text{abc}  \\
          h=\phantom{\displaystyle \sum_{i\in I} a_i} \hspace{-3.5\tabcolsep}\text{abc}  
      \end{matrix}
      \]
\end{document}
```